# Given inscribed rectangle, how to do you call the shape in which the rectangle is inscribed?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Let's say I have a square inscribed into circle. Then how do you call the circle in relation to the rectangle?

Now I need proper naming convention for shapes in general.

[image: inscribed rectangle sketch]

Comment: Stay with the "inscribed in" relation. It won't cause any confusion. For the case of a rectangle inscribed in a circle, as AugSB's commented, the circle is the circumscribed circle. For a square inscribed in a rectangle, you would need to indicate _how_ it is inscribed.

Comment: The circle is the [circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle). I do not know any particular name for general shapes.

Comment: Image a video with fixed aspect ratio that has to fit into screen with given size (pixels), so entire video will be visible (letterboxing with symetrical black bars)

I have a funcion called `GetInscribedRectangle` that calculates the position of the scaled video preview inside the UI element: `Rect GetInscribedRect(Size originalSize, Size sizeToFit)`. 

How would you describe the the second parameter?

Comment: "enclosed disk" or "biggest area enclosed disk" or "smaller area enclosing disk", more generally "enclosed _something_", or  "enclosing _something_", for example "enclosed rectangle", or "enclosing rectangle" are common composite keywords in **image processing**.

Comment: Thks. I have written it as an answer with some added information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"enclosed" or "enclosing". But in general associated to a function that has to be either minimized of maximized. E.g., "biggest area enclosed disk" or "smaller area enclosing disk", more generally "enclosed *something*", or "enclosing *something*", for example "enclosed rectangle", or "enclosing rectangle" are common composite keywords in image processing. A common adjective for this class of objects is "bounding object".

In Matlab, for example, you can consult (https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects)

A more general site is (http://www.mlahanas.de/CompGeom/opt_bbox.htm)